# Unable to play one array of videos for an hour

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have array of multiple videos. Right now, the code below works in that it plays multiple videos one after the other. However, they are time agnostic, and I specifically want to play these videos for exactly one hour. How can I achieve this using Javascript?

```
<body onload="myNewSrc()">
    <div id="section-title">
        <video onended="myAddListener()" autoplay controls width="100%" height="auto">
            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <script>
        var videoSources = ["http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
            "http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4",
            "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
            "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
            "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
        ];
        var currentIndex = 0;
        //listener function changes src
        function myNewSrc() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
            myVideo.load();
        }

        function myAddListener() {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoSources.length;
            myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
            myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to body, then inside that get the current time using `Date.now()` and store it in some variable.

Then compare the stored time to the current time every time a video finishes playing. If more than one hour has elapsed, then end the playback.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var startTime;
var videoSources = 
["http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4", "http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];
var currentIndex =0;
//listener function changes src
function myNewSrc(){
    startTime = new Date;
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src=videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.load();
}
function myAddListener(){

    if ((new Date) - startTime > (60 * 60 * 1000)) {
        return;
    }
    var myVideo=document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    currentIndex=(currentIndex+1)%videoSources.length;
    myVideo.src=videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myNewSrc,false);
}
```

Comment: above code not solve my problem. @Shane . Video list is running for more than a hour.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how a more worldly-wise stackoverflow user would put it, but: SO members are not paid coders and will not write code for you for free. We're happy to fill you in on a concept you might be missing and we hope you value our advice. And among the two answers provided here I do believe you have enough sample code / content to work off. Come on man.

Comment: though as for why the above code is not working: the `myNewSrc` function is being called because the event is propagating up to the body when the video loads. That's one of the more novel problems i've seen :3